# JavaScript Syntax Question - function returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript

When I log this to the console it shows up as undefined. However, when I remove the braces in the function it logs the desired result. I'm confused -- aren't we always supposed to include curly braces in a function? Thank you all.

```
const shoutGreetings = arr => {
  arr.map(word => word.toUpperCase() + '!')
};

const greetings = ['hello', 'hi', 'heya', 'oi', 'hey', 'yo'];
console.log(shoutGreetings(greetings))
```

Comment: You can omit the braces in an arrow function if it's a single expression. Then it automatically returns the value of that expression.

Comment: But if you have braces, you need to use `return` if you want it to return something.

Comment: @Barmar is right. In one case you are (automatically) returning the result of `map` and in the other, you are not, as this (automatic) returning stops when you introduce curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

Return the result of your `map` function:
`return arr.map(...`